# First item in selectfield is always checked and never updates field in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Am having a problem with the following selectfield on my form:

```
 {
                xtype: 'selectfield',
                label: 'Title',
                displayField: 'ItemName',
                valueField: 'Id',
                listeners: {
                    initialize: function () {
                        var titleStore = Ext.create('MyApp.store.Titles', {});
                        this.setStore(titleStore);
                    }
                }
},
```

On the form which uses the selectfield, whenever I select the option the form updates correctly, but the first item in the list always has a check mark against it. Also when selecting the first item in the list never updates the form.  My knowledge of ST is limited but surely this should work out of the box?

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was down to a silly error.  The data coming from the server had identical 'Id' values, so when an item in the list was selected it had the same value as the rest of the items. The select field would then just show the first item that matched the 'Id' value which would be the first in the list.